# Magento default iPhone theme: How to edit CMS page or more generally the home page

Tags: iphone, magento, mobile, magento-1.7

Using the default Magento iPhone theme, I am trying to simply edit the home page content, then eventually the layout itself.

I am aware of changing CMS content through CMS->Pages, however this only seems to relate to the Default theme rather than the mobile theme.

For example, in the two images below we see the content area of the mobile version which displays three categories, and secondly the Pages->CMS content editor for home page. The two clearly do not relate to the same information.

Can anyone help me find out how the iphone home page content is editied?

Image 1 - iphone homepage (green circled area is content):

[image]

Image 2 - Pages->CMS Homepage

[image]